# String variable passed from View to Controller always arrive as NULL in Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass data from the View to the Controller with an Ajax call.
The following simplified code passes NULL every time.
Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong please?

Index.cshtml:

```
<input type="submit" id="ajaxTestButton" value="Pass To Controller" />

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var testData = "Fred";

        $("#ajaxTestButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: testData,
                contentType: "text/plain",
                url: '@Url.Action("ButtonTest", "Home")'
            });
    });
    </script>
```

HomeController.cs:

```
namespace TestingAjax.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void ButtonTest(string Name)
        {
            // Do something interesting here.
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting string Name to be "Fred".
Thank you.

Comment: comment removed.

Comment: I don't think asp.net core has default support for the text/plain media type formatter so it is probably falling back to json. You could add a custom formatter or send json instead and use the [FromBody] attribute on the controller argument.

Comment: @Allu Try posting data as `data : {Name : "value"}` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired functionality using `AJAX` to `POST` your form variables to controller, refer to the following code snippet:

```
<input type="submit" id="ajaxTestButton" value="Pass To Controller" />

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
        var yourName= "Fred";
        var json = {
                   Name: yourName
                   };

        $("#ajaxTestButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ButtonTest", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json) },
            success: function (data) {
             //If there is no error from the server
             },
             error: function (data) {
             //If there is an error from the server
             },
        });
});
</script>
```

And in your controller, you can get your value like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
namespace TestingAjax.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void ButtonTest(string json)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
            //Get your Name variable here
            string name= jsondata["Name"];
            // Do something interesting here.
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Allu I hope this helped you in your problem. It is more of a `JSON` approach instead of `FormData` approach.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I prefer this solution as it **is** more ```JSON``` (our preferred option here) and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Passing your json data using Formdata, Now you create GET and POST Action in controller.

```
    <input type="submit" id="ajaxTestButton" value="Pass To Controller" />

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Name", "fred");

        $("#ajaxTestButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("ButtonTest", "Home")'
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. this gives me an error: jquery.js:8463 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at add (jquery.js:8463)
    at buildParams (jquery.js:8450)
    at Function.jQuery.param (jquery.js:8483)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9073)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):38)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)

Comment: @Allu am happy to help you please accept my answer see : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" id="ajaxTestButton" value="Pass To Controller" />

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var testData = "Fred";

        $("#ajaxTestButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { 'Name': testData },
                contentType: "text/plain",
                url: '@Url.Action("ButtonTest", "Home")'
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Aamir but it still comes through as null.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to serialize the form.

Keep in mind, in the controller action will be expecting your form type.
This is a great approach, if you have a form type MyViewModel that will be the type to be expected on the controller action. All properties  will be serialized and maped.

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#ajaxTestButton").click(function () {
            var form = $('form');
        $.ajax( {
              type: "POST",
              url: form.attr( 'action' ),
              data: form.serialize(),
              success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
              }
            } );

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.